# What is the name of this geometric shape?

Tags: geometry, terminology

### #1

I am trying to find the name for this when $d1 = d2$

[image]

What is the name of this object?

### #2

Assume d1 is different than d2. 
What is the name of this kind of object?

Comment: A six sided polygon is called hexagon, and since in your case you have different angle measures , then it must be called irregular hexagon

Comment: What are $d_1$ and $d_2$? Are they the side lengths?

Comment: @Arpan Yes, d1 and d2 are side lengths.

Comment: @alkabary Can you make this `irregular hexagon` even more precise? I think there may be other irregular hexagons which may collide with this type of specific form.

Comment: A concave hexagon with two [mouths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_%28geometry%29#Mouths) along a principal diagonal? you can also add other modifiers like "symmetric under reflection with respect to a plane perpendicular to that diagonal" if appropriate.

Comment: I don't believe there's an official name for this shape, so the trick is to find a concise descriptor. "Concave bisymmetric hexagon" would (I think) cover #1, but there's no elegant counterpart for #2. Of course, you're free to call these things whatever you like. I might be inclined to play off of the resemblance to an [anvil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anvil).

Comment: How about a *bowtie hexagon*?  http://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/substitution_rules/bowtie_hexagon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call them *hourglass hexagons*.

---

[image]

---

<sup>(Image source: [link](https://www.interaction-design.org/ux-daily/189/the-impact-of-small-decisions-and-hourglass-focus).)</sup>

Comment: Why has the shape of hourglass selected as it is? It wouls be very nice get some review on this.

Comment: @Masi: One needs two equal-volume chambers, symmetry (for flipping upsidedown), and a narrow neck for the sand trickle.